# Suitable choices of base functions for periodic signals using Koopman approximation

Tags: dynamical-systems, spectral-theory, periodic-functions, approximation-theory, hermite-polynomials

[This article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00332-015-9258-5) explains the extended dynamic mode decomposition (EDMD) algorithm. It is about the spectral decomposition of nonlinear dynamics based on the Koopman operator theory.

Particularly, it is about the finite approximation $\mathbf{K}$ of the Koopman operator $\mathcal{K}$

> $$ (\mathcal{K}\psi)(\mathbf{x}) = (\mathbf{\Psi} \; \circ \;
>  \mathbf{F})(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{a} =
>  \mathbf{\Psi}(\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{K}\mathbf{a}) + r(\mathbf{x}), 
> $$

where $\mathbf{\Psi}$ denotes a tuple of so called *observables* which are basically base functions of the spectral decomposition, $\mathbf{F}$ is a mapping from manifold to manifold, $\mathbf{a}$ are weighting coefficients, and $r$ is an error that needs to be minimized.

In the example given for a Koopman-based approximation of a linear time-invariant (LTI) dynamical system with two states $(x_1, x_2)$, permutations of products of hermite polynomials $H_i(x)H_j(y), i,j=0...4$ are used as base functions, as in

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{\Psi}(\mathbf{x}) & = & \left( \psi_{00}(\mathbf{x}), \psi_{01}(\mathbf{x}), \psi_{02}(\mathbf{x}), ..., \psi_{44}(\mathbf{x}) \right) \\ & = & \left( H_0(x_1)H_0(x_2), H_0(x_1)H_1(x_2), ..., H_4(x_1)H_4(x_2) \right).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

While this attempt works well for the given LTI case, it fails for data which exhibits periodic patterns, like this one:

[image]

My questions are:

1. What base functions $(\psi_{00}, \psi_{01}, ...)$ are promising candidates for the periodic signal?
2. What makes this particular choice of hermite polynomials suitable for the example system?